# Should I flag questions that are recruitment tests?

Tags: discussion, ethics

**While the specific context here is from Stack Overflow, the question being asked here is *not* only relevant to Stack Overflow, and can be applied to other technical sites as well.**

Found a question where an algorithm is posted, and its problem is

> 14% mark in codility

The question's merit notwithstanding, I Googled "codility" and apparently it's a platform where recruiters can give candidates programming tasks.

So, asking a question that came from a place like that is likely an infringement of trust of some sort, though we can't be sure (could be an already failed task that the candidate is still wondering about).

Should I flag something like that? Or is it the asker's responsibility?

(asked in stack exchange meta, debated if it fits there or here, copying here while it's debated - [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333326/should-i-flag-questions-that-are-recruitment-tests))